# ScheduledExecutorService problem with Autowired service

Tags: java, spring, autowired, scheduledexecutorservice

I am trying to make a `ScheduledExecutor` service to run `MyTask` every day at certain time. The problem I have is that the task uses `@Service` component, and if I do `@Autowire` without `@Component`, the service won't work, if I put the `@Component` the `MyTask` runs first no matter the component where `Scheduler` is.

I tried sending the service through constructor and `@DependsOn` but it didn't work.

```
@Component
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

@Autowired
private Service service;

@Override
public void run() {

    //some code

    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTask(),
        initalDelay,
        TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(1),
        TimeUnit.SECONDS);


}}
```

if `@Component` is put here, this runs first

```
 public class MyTask extends TimerTask {

    @Autowired
    private Service service;
 }
```

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. What's the problem with the `Service`?

Comment: and why don't you use `@Schedule` annotation from spring?

Comment: @AlexR it doesn't work in MyTask

Comment: @Deadpool I want to run the task at certain time, like 5AM, with dynamical initial delay.

Comment: do you want to run task at 5Am every day? and what do you mean by this `with dynamical initial delay` @M8765 can you please tell at what time and which day you want to run task?

Comment: I want to run the task every day at 5AM. But that is not the point of my question, the problem is not with scheduler, it works fine, the service in my task doesn't.

Comment: Ofcourse it will be `null`... You are creating an instance yourself, outside of Spring and hence it will not get the Spring treatment. Also why not simply make a `MyTask` method that does something and annotate with `@Scheduled`? Saves you writing all the boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

Define Task as

public class MyTask extends TimerTask {

```
private final DataSetService dataSetService

public MyTask(DataSetService dataSetService) {
 this.dataSetService = dataSetService;
}

// Your other code here
```

}

and your MyRunnable as

```
@Component 
public class MyScheduler {

@Autowired
private final DataSetService dataSetService

private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

@PostConstruct
public void startScheduler() {
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTask(dataSetService),
        initalDelay,
        TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(1),
        TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

As you can see, MyRunnable (now renamed MyScheduler) no more implements the unnecessary Runnable, it is a spring bean, and after it is instantiated the PostConstruct starts the scheduler.

Comment: I wrote that I tried that, and even it does recognize a value in service if I print it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh sorry I noticed another thing, Why do you create MyRunnable as Component? In this way you are forcing Spring to instantiate MyRunnable as bean. So removing Component from MyRunnable force you to have a third class, this one with Component, with the necessary Autowired, then instantiating the ScheduledExecutorService. Another options would be to use [Quartz] (http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)

Comment: It has to be a Component, it has other code that I didn't show.

Comment: Again, the problem is not with scheduler, but with service not working.

Comment: I edited the response to catch your notes. I hope it makes more sense now

Comment: Thanks for trying, but the value is not the issue, I can see it when I send it through constructor. The mistake happens later, with some proxy handling, like it has to be registered somewhere or something like that.

Comment: What is package of your *private **Service** service*

Comment: The exception I am getting is:
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext has been closed already.

Answer (score 0):

You are making things more complex then necessary. Spring can handle the scheduling for you which will make the autowaring work. Without you needing to specify all the boilerplate.

Basically ditch the `MyRunnable`, don't extend `TimerTask` in your `MyTask`. Annotate your `MyTask` as `@Component` and slap an `@Scheduled` on the method you want to execute. (As you have extended `TimerTask` initially probably the `run` method).

```java
@Component
public class MyTask {

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 5 * * *")
    public void run() { ... } 
 }
```

If you really want to keep the complexity, you can do 2 things. Add the `@Component` annotation to `MyTask` and inject that into the `MyRunnable` as well, use that reference in the scheduling. Or you can remove the `@Autowired`, make the field `final` and create a constructor that takes the `Service` dependency and does the setup in the constructor.

However I would strongly suggest using the simpler `@Scheduled` and if you need an initial delay, put that calculation into a separate bean and use a SpEL expression to get the `initialDelay`.